# "Down" "Null" "Up" logistic regression

Tags: logistic, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am familiar with binomial (logistic) regression and with multinomial regression based thereon. Is there a technique specifically adapted to "trinomial" data, where the data can be represented -1, 0, +1, where 0 is "no change", "-1" is "reduced", and "+1" is "increased"? To further complicate matters, the effect is relatively rare (141 +, 66 -, 15187 0).

It's essentially ordinal response regression, but specifically limited.

Comment: What model would you propose for your response?  If you're not sure, then it would help us to know what the response actually is and how it's measured.

Comment: I am not familiar with any trinomial logistic regression, however there is multinomial (ordinal) logistic regression.

Comment: That's all I know of, too. I was just wondering (hoping) about a special case method to be used when one value was "less than zero", one was "zero", and one was "more than zero", especially when the vast majority of the data is zeroes (no effect).